# kafka -> flink - performance issues

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

Im looking at some kafka topics that generate ~30K messages / second. I have a flink topology setup to read one of these, aggregate a bit (5 second window) and then (eventually) write to a DB.

When I run my topology and remove everything but the read -> aggregate steps I can only get ~30K messages *per minute*. There isn't anywhere for backpressure to occur.

What am I doing wrong?

---

### Edit:

1. I can't change anything about the topic space. Each topic has a single partition and there are hundreds of them.
2. Each message is a compressed thrift object averaging 2-3Kb

It appears that I'm only able to get ~1.5 MB/s. Not v close to the 100MB/s mentioned.

The current code path:

```
DataStream<byte[]> dataStream4 = env.addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer081<>("data_4", new RawSchema(), parameterTool.getProperties())).setParallelism(1);  
DataStream<Tuple4<Long, Long, Integer, String>> ds4 = dataStream4.rebalance().flatMap(new mapper2("data_4")).setParallelism(4);
```

---

```
public class mapper2 implements FlatMapFunction<byte[], Tuple4<Long, Long, Integer, String>> {
    private String mapId;
    public mapper2(String mapId) {
        this.mapId = mapId;
    }

    @Override
    public void flatMap(byte[] bytes, Collector<Tuple4<Long, Long, Integer, String>> collector) throws Exception {
        TimeData timeData = (TimeData)ts_thriftDecoder.fromBytes(bytes);
        Tuple4 tuple4 = new Tuple4<Long, Long, Integer, String>();
        tuple4.f0 = timeData.getId();
        tuple4.f1 = timeData.getOtherId();
        tuple4.f2 = timeData.getSections().size();
        tuple4.f3 = mapId;

        collector.collect(tuple4);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you getting the ~30K msg/sec figure? From your own tests? If you read it somewhere, can you provide links?

Comment: I have the producer code and can read the throughput from there.

Comment: So your producer is producing at ~30K msg/sec, but your consumer is only consuming at ~30K msg/min?

Comment: Yes. That's what I'm seeing. I know that once the data gets into flink it goes very rapidly. I have another topo that pushes >6M records /min into cassandra. Im wondering if there is some inherent bottleneck with the kafka consumer **FlinkKafkaConsumer081**.  Note that this topic only has a single partition. Could this be a problem?

Comment: Okay. That makes sense. You might want to edit your questions to more clearly state those things, and/or any other facts you noticed based on my question your your debugging.

Comment: I've used the FlinkKafkaConsumer to read ~100MB/s of data from Kafka. What's the size of a Kafka message?
How are the messages serialized? How are you deserializing the data from the Kafka messages? For coming up with the number I've mentioned above, I needed to heavily optimize my serializers.

Comment: The number of Kafka partitions basically limit the maximum degree of parallelism with which data can be read from Kafka. Thus, I'd recommend you to set the partition number to at least the number of your parallelism in your Flink job.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the code, I see two potential components which could cause the performance issues:

- The FlinkKafkaConsumer
- The Thrift deserializer

In order to understand where the bottleneck is, I would first measure the raw read performance of Flink reading from the Kafka topic.

Therefore, can you run the following code on your cluster?

```java
public class RawKafka {

private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RawKafka.class);

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

    ParameterTool parameterTool = ParameterTool.fromArgs(args);
    DataStream<byte[]> dataStream4 = env.addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer081<>("data_4", new RawSchema(), parameterTool.getProperties())).setParallelism(1);

    dataStream4.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<byte[], Integer>() {
        long received = 0;
        long logfreq = 50000;
        long lastLog = -1;
        long lastElements = 0;

        @Override
        public void flatMap(byte[] element, Collector<Integer> collector) throws Exception {
            received++;
            if (received % logfreq == 0) {
                // throughput over entire time
                long now = System.currentTimeMillis();

                // throughput for the last "logfreq" elements
                if(lastLog == -1) {
                    // init (the first)
                    lastLog = now;
                    lastElements = received;
                } else {
                    long timeDiff = now - lastLog;
                    long elementDiff = received - lastElements;
                    double ex = (1000/(double)timeDiff);
                    LOG.info("During the last {} ms, we received {} elements. That's {} elements/second/core. GB received {}",
                            timeDiff, elementDiff, elementDiff*ex, (received * 2500) / 1024 / 1024 / 1024);
                    // reinit
                    lastLog = now;
                    lastElements = received;
                }
            }
        }
    });

    env.execute("Raw kafka throughput");
}
}
```

This code is measuring the time between 50k elements from Kafka and logging the number of elements read from Kafka.
On my local machine I got a throughput of ~330k elements/core/second:

```
16:09:34,028 INFO  RawKafka                                                      - During the last 88 ms, we received 30000 elements. That's 340909.0909090909 elements/second/core. GB received 0
16:09:34,028 INFO  RawKafka                                                      - During the last 86 ms, we received 30000 elements. That's 348837.20930232556 elements/second/core. GB received 0
16:09:34,028 INFO  RawKafka                                                      - During the last 85 ms, we received 30000 elements. That's 352941.17647058825 elements/second/core. GB received 0
16:09:34,028 INFO  RawKafka                                                      - During the last 88 ms, we received 30000 elements. That's 340909.0909090909 elements/second/core. GB received 0
16:09:34,030 INFO  RawKafka                                                      - During the last 90 ms, we received 30000 elements. That's 333333.3333333333 elements/second/core. GB received 0
16:09:34,030 INFO  RawKafka                                                      - During the last 91 ms, we received 30000 elements. That's 329670.3296703297 elements/second/core. GB received 0
16:09:34,030 INFO  RawKafka                                                      - During the last 85 ms, we received 30000 elements. That's 352941.17647058825 elements/second/core. GB received 0
```

I'm really interested to see which throughput you are achieving reading from Kafka.

Comment: I have to apologize for this whole issue. Based on the output of your tool I went back and examined the way we measure 'flow' at the producer. There were some semantic issues with what we measure and the values it reports. The long and short of it: I was able to read ~5K messages / second and I suspect it will go higher.

Comment: No problem. Let me know if you need further advise improving the performance.

Comment: @rmetzger Thanks for the tool ! Using it I found I'm consuming at the rate of **70 MB/s** without special serializers (used `SimpleStringSchema`). That's upto ~35K msg/s. I want to optimize my msg/s using `Avro/Byte[]`. Can you specify how do I start.

Comment: What do you want to optimize?

Comment: @rmetzger My current throughput is ~35K msg/s, Is there any way to increase it, as `~352941 elements/second/core`  in your case

Comment: What's the disk speed of the servers running the Kafka brokers?
I assume you have one broker per server, right? One broker can maybe serve 80% of the raw disk speed.
What's the size of each of your messages? I think in my example its just a few bytes. That's why the throughput is so high.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used Flink or it's KafkaConsumer, but I have experience with Kafka in a Storm environment. Here are some thoughts that I have. There's a lot of variables at play with how Kafka speed is determined. Here are some things to think about and investigate, add more details to your question when you have them.

- Adding more partitions should increase your throughput. So yes, adding more partitions and consumers should see a somewhat linear jump in performance.
- Kafka throughput is relative to message size. So if you have big messages the throughput will suffer accordingly.
- Do you have any evidence to support your expectation that Kafka Consumer should be faster? While I would agree that 30K msg/min is really slow, do you have evidence to back up your expectation? Like a general speed test using the FlinkKafkaConsumer (something like [this](https://engineering.linkedin.com/kafka/benchmarking-apache-kafka-2-million-writes-second-three-cheap-machines)), or using the plain Kafka consumer to see what the speed of consuming is and then comparing that to Flink's Consumer?

There could be a lot of reasons why its consuming slowly, I've tried to highlight some of the general Kafka related stuff. I'm sure there are probably things you can do in Flink to speed up consuming that I don't know about because I've never used it.